# How to use trailing closure in if condition?

Tags: swift

Here is the code:

```
class Person {
}

func lastNameForPerson(person: Person, caseFolding: ((String)->(String))? = nil) -> String {
    if let folder = caseFolding {
        return folder("Smith")
    }
    return "Smith"
}

print(lastNameForPerson(Person())) // Prints "Smith"
print(lastNameForPerson(Person()) {$0.uppercaseString}) // Prints "SMITH"

if "SMITH" == lastNameForPerson(Person()) {$0.uppercaseString} {
    print("It's bob")
}
```

Was expecting to get "It's bob". But instead got the error:

> Consecutive statements must be separated by a new line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to put parentheses around the function call:

```
if "SMITH" == (lastNameForPerson(Person()) {$0.uppercaseString}) {
    print("It's bob")
}
```

Or you put them around the `==` comparison (around the `if` condition) in a C-style manner:

```
if ("SMITH" == lastNameForPerson(Person()) {$0.uppercaseString}) {
    print("It's bob")
}
```

Alternatively, you can move the closure inside the parameter list (though this requires you to explicitly name the parameter):

```
if "SMITH" == lastNameForPerson(Person(), caseFolding: {$0.uppercaseString}) {
    print("It's bob")
}
```

The reason this problem arises is that the `if` statement 'claims' the `{}` block, i.e. it doesn't belong to the `lastNameForPerson` call any more. For the compiler, the second code block now looks like a normal block that wasn't properly separated from the previous (`if`) statement.

---

You should probably consider avoiding a construct like this in general, since it might be hard to read (at first). Instead, you could store the result of the function call in a variable and compare that instead:

```
let lastName = lastNameForPerson(Person()) {$0.uppercaseString}
if "SMITH" == lastName {
    print("It's bob")
}
```

Comment: In the second block of code you forgot the name of the param `caseFolding` when invoking the function. At present it does not compile

Answer (score 1):

Put your function call between parentheses:

```
if "SMITH" == (lastNameForPerson(Person()) {$0.uppercaseString}) {
```

otherwise the `==` operator takes precedence and the compiler evaluates it as

```
if ("SMITH" == lastNameForPerson(Person())) {$0.uppercaseString} {
```

which is not valid code.