# Swift: Cannot call value of non function type - trailing closure

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the following the line of code

```
if let a = assetConfigs.first { $0.code == cells[2] }
{...}
```

`assetConfigs` is an array of objects of the `AssetConfig` type which has a property called `code`

I get the error

```
Cannot call value of non-function type AssetConfig?
```

I just want the first asset config which has the same code as the value contained in cells[2]. Array under Swift has the function called `first` which returns the first object which meets a certain condition. (https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1848165-first)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you disambiguate the curly braces `if let a = assetConfigs.first(where: { $0.code == cells[2] })`?

Comment: You need to use parenthesis in order to disambiguate the trailing closure, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/34930596/2976878

Comment: OK I see - because the compiler can't tell whether I'm calling the property 'first' and then starting my if statement block or calling the function 'first' with a trailing closure. I get it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having this same issue, but disambiguating doesn't seem to fix it.  If you have this compiling and working, please provide an example in an answer to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subtle gotcha here that can hide the underlying syntax error.  Even with a disambiguated call, if the body of the closure has an error in it, the compiler will report that it cannot call the value of a non-function type.  By fixing the error in the closure, it will compile:

**Cannot call the value of a non-function type**

```
let a = assetConfigs.first(where: { $0.code == "TEST" /* incompatible types */ }) {
  ...
}
```

**Compiles:**

```
let a = assetConfigs.first(where: { $0.code == cells[2] }) {
  ...
}
```

I seems this results from there being two definitions of the Array member function `first`, and the compiler is choosing the *first* problem it identifies - that the member function `first` that returns an optional array element is not a function.